# node programmatically set process environment variables not available to imported modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

I'm new, hopefully this question is properly formatted and formulated. Can't wait to see your answers on this question. Let's get to it..

## Context

Past weekend I was trying to implement `es2015` syntax support in my `create-react-app` configuration files, which was straight forward. All I had to do was use `babel-register` and `babel-preset-env` to get it working. So far so good you could say, however it wasn't all good. After some hours of searching I found that `process.env` variables are not passed through to imported modules. The code below will demonstrate my issue.

## The code

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": [
    "good": "NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node -r babel-register scripts/start.js",
    "bad": "node -r babel-register scripts/start.js"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [ "env" ]
}
```

**scripts/start.js**

```
'use strict'

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';

// Always works
const a = require('../src/a');
// Only when environment variables are passed in via the CLI
import b from '../src/b';

console.log('Bye bye..');
```

**src/a.js**

```
'use strict'

console.log('Module A:', process.env.NODE_ENV);

const a = { name: "Module A" };
export default a;
```

**src/b.js**

```
'use strict'

console.log('Module B:', process.env.NODE_ENV);

const b = { name: "Module B" };
export default b;
```

## Running the code

Below you will see the output of both `npm` scripts:

```
npm run good
# Outputs:
Module B: development
Module A: development
Bye bye..

npm run bad
# Outputs:
Module B: undefined
Module A: development
Bye bye..
```

## My question(s)

1. Why aren't programmatically set environment variables passed through to imported modules?
2. Can this be fixed while keeping es2015 syntax? (e.g. using a babel plugin?)

## More info

Just moving my `process.env.NODE_PATH` over to the CLI won't work, `create-react-app` programmatically sets environment variables at multiple places in their configuration/script files. I have listed a few links below, pointing to the `create-react-app` repo and some of the files that are giving me troubles.

- [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) A link to the `create-react-app` repo.
- [scripts/start.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js) This script sets both `process.env.NODE_ENV` and `process.env.BABEL_ENV`.
- [config/env.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js) This config file sets `process.env.NODE_PATH`.

## Note(s)

From my current understanding, `create-react-app` has little to none to do with the problem I'm having. I'm interested in why programmatically set environment variables are not passed through to imported modules.

## My setup

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Node: v8.11.2
- Npm: 6.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES6 imports are hoisted. This means they will run before the rest of the code regardless of where they are in the source. The result is that `b.js` will run before you have set `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'`.

Babel's output will be consistent with this and will simulate hoisted imports by moving `b`'s require statement to the top of the file. Babel will create a `start` file that looks like:

```
'use strict';

var _b = require('../src/b');

var _b2 = _interopRequireDefault(_b);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';

// Always works
var a = require('../src/a');
// Only when environment variables are passed in via the CLI
```

It should be clear looking at that why this isn't working.

[ *As a side note, many people strongly recommend that you don't set `NODE_ENV` at runtime* ]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark Meyer, I have up voted your answer and will mark it as the right answer later today (or tomorrow). Yes, it's super clear why what I want isn't working. As per your side note; Am I chasing unicorns trying to get ES6 and runtime environment variables to work at the same time? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @sxkx, I'm really not sure. I haven't tried using ES6 modules like this, nor have I done anything where I'm setting the NODE_ENV at runtime.

Comment: I found a solution to my second question. It was a rather simple one, see my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

## Answer to my second question

Thanks to the insights provided by **@Mark Meyer** I was able to get it to work.

**scripts/start.js**

```
'use strict'  

import '../config/devEnv';
```

**config/devEnv.js**

```
'use strict'  

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
```

Now the environment variable setters are hoisted as well, making them available to all imported modules.

Comment: This is a very helpful technique!